# creating dat file with increasing number of order in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have

```
particle:: add_particle(int i)
      {

         ofstream fp1;
        fp1.open("output/particle.dat",ios::binary);


        fp1.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));

        fp1.close();

          }

          fp1.close();
      }
```

and loop this addition using

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
    {

            p.add_particle(i);



    }
```

however during each loop ,I want the file name to be
particle0.dat
particle1.dat
particle2.dat and so on;

How can I acheive it in visual C++;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i ) {
    std::stringstream str;
    str << "output/particle" << i << ".dat";
    fp1.open(str.str().c_str(), ios::binary);
    ...
}
```

You can specify number formatting with:

```
str.width(2);
str.fill('0');
...
```

See: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream

Comment: #include <sstream> need to be included so as to make the above code not to show the error

Answer (score 0):

sprintf would can be useful for your case.

```
// create a  variable for storing the output buffer
// the following should execute in loop

char buffer[200];
int value = 0;
sprintf(buffer, "output/particle%d.dat", value);
value++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not just having a problem formatting a string and are looking to keep incrementing file names across multiple runs you have to examine the files that are already in place. To do that you have to use FindFirstFile and friends. A rudimentary example:

```
unsigned int currentFileNumber(const char *dir, const char *start)
{
    unsigned int ret = 0;
    unsigned int len;
    _Bool matched;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
    HANDLE hfind;
    char best[MAX_PATH] = "";
    char pattern[MAX_PATH];

    snprintf(pattern, sizeof(pattern), "%s\\%s???.dat", dir, start);
    hfind = FindFirstFile(pattern, &fd);
    if (hfind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        len = strlen(fd.cFileName);
        matched = isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-7]) && isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-6]) && isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-5]);
        do {
            len = strlen(fd.cFileName);
            if (((fd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
            && isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-7])
            && isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-6])
            && isdigit(fd.cFileName[len-5])
            && (!matched || (strcmp(best, fd.cFileName) < 0))) {
                matched = 1;
                strcpy(best, fd.cFileName);
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hfind, &fd));
        FindClose(hfind);
        if (matched) {
            ret = (100 * (best[len-7] - '0')) + (10 * (best[len-6] - '0')) + (best[len-5] - '0') + 1;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

static void currentFileName(const char *dir, char *dest, size_t size)
{
    unsigned int n;

    n = currentFileNumber(dir, "particle");
    snprintf(dest, size, "%s%3.3u.dat", start, n);
}
```